# How can I convert this to async-await code and use only 1 thread?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have a piece of code like

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to print 'Hello, world!' after 2 seconds");
    while(true)
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
        Task.Run(() => 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hello world! (from thread {0})", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });
    }
}
```

which of course creates a lot of threads if I press keys fast, and those threads are doing nothing besides waiting for the first 2 seconds that they are used.

I want to change the action to have

```
await Task.Delay(2000).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

but I can't figure out how to chain the `async`-`await`s "all the way up" to make this work.

Comment: `Task.Run( async () => ` ? In order to be able to use `await` you need the Action to be an async Action.

Comment: @Fildor That's just using additional threads for less time, it's still using additional threads (unnecessarily) though.

Comment: @Servy I only addressed the "I want to change the action to have `await Task.Delay...`" - part, yes. Hence not an answer.

Comment: Asynchronous single threaded code is a little tricky in console applications. Can you explain why you're trying to do this? Normally you'd try to keep your code affinitized to one thread in GUI scenarios, not console scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements aren't entirely clear (do you literally need to use *no* additional threads? is using `Task.Delay()` an integral part of your goal?), nor what specifically you're having trouble figuring out.

If you can accept some *small number* of additional threads, then `Task.Delay()` would work for you. Of course, you need for it to be in an `async` method so you can `await` it. IMHO, this is done more correctly in a named method rather than anonymous:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to print 'Hello, world!' after 2 seconds");
    while(true)
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
        KeyPressed();
    }
}

// WARNING: "async void" is discouraged!
private static async void KeyPressed()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hello world! (from thread {0})", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

Note:

- It is generally not a good idea to use `void` for `async` methods. But in your example, an exception is unlikely and you don't appear to want to wait for the method's completion anyway, so I've written the above using `void` anyway. In your real-world scenario, consider carefully whether this is really appropriate. At the very least, if an exception could occur, you should then put a `try`/`catch` handler in the `async` method to ensure the exception is observed.
- In a console program, there's not any need to use `ConfigureAwait()`, because you don't have a synchronization context for a continuation to resume on in the first place. Continuations will occur in the thread pool.
- The above does not literally *"use only 1 thread"*. Since (as I mention just above) the continuation happens in the thread pool (there's no mechanism for it to get back to the main thread), there will still be additional threads used. However, it should be fewer than the number you were using before, because a thread is required only for the continuation. The delay happens using a timer thread (okay, so there's one more thread there…but that's shared with all the timers). It's likely this approach would involve only a handful of extra threads, no matter how frequently you press a key.

I don't see any way to literally get the solution down to just one thread (i.e. one user-created thread….NET creates threads behind your back anyway, so you're never going to literally have a .NET process with only one thread), unless you use polling instead of the `ReadKey()` method for input. Which you could do, but it'd be a very inefficient use of CPU time. IMHO, the `async`/`await` approach strikes the best balance between simplicity and efficiency.